# Use a dictionary to replace values in a list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

If I had a dict containing `{'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}` and I want to use these keys to replace the contents of list `l = ['z', 'q', 'f']` with their corresponding value, how would I do it?

When I first tried to solve this problem, I figured I could enter something like list[i] = get.(i) for i in dict.  That doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}

l = ['b', 'c', 'a']

new_list = [my_dict[x] for x in l]
```

Of course, that's assuming you have a key for every element in the `l` list. Afterwards you can then do `l = list(new_list)`. If you want to still use the `l` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below should take care of corner case scenarios ...

- cyclic keys occurring in dictionary (e.g. {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'})
- key is repeating multiple times in list (e.g. ['b', 'c', 'a', 'z', 'b', 'c'])
- key in list doesn't exists in dictionary's keys (e.g. 'z')

Here are 2 solutions, one by updating same list and second by creating new list.

Updating same list

```
dictionary = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
l = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'z', 'b', 'c']

print(l)
position = 0
for item in l:
    if item in dictionary.keys():
        l[position] = dictionary[item]
    position = position + 1
print(l)
```

Creating new list

```
dictionary = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
l = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'z', 'b', 'c']
nl = []
for item in l:
    if item in dictionary.keys():
        nl.append(dictionary[item])
    else:
        nl.append(item)
print(l)
print(nl)
```

Sample Run

```
======= RESTART: C:/listByMap.py =======
['b', 'c', 'a', 'z', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'd', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'd']
```